# Optimizing index difference of equal values for time complexity

Tags: python, optimization

I have this code that finds the smallest difference between the indices of equal values in a list. (It finds the smallest "distance" between equal values.) I want to optimize its time complexity. My code currently runs in O(N^2).

```
def func(arr):
    length = len(arr)
    res = 0
    for i and j in range(length):
            if arr[i] == arr[j]:
                res = min(res,i-j)
    return res
```

How can I optimize it?

Comment: Think about sorting and how you can solve the problem by using it

Comment: @user2548635 I am unable to wrap my head around this. I tried but couldn't figure out a way. Can you provide?

Comment: You should also say what the type of things in the array are. The correct answer depends on whether the items are hashable.

Comment: I updated the question and title with what I believe the code is supposed to do. Please review my change and make sure it's correct. If not, please clarify, and feel free to reword it if you don't like how I did. ...I really don't like what I did with the title. Feel free to change it, but the old one was way too vague.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simple solution that has **O(n)** time complexity. For every item in the array it will store the first index it's found from and then later retrieves it to calculate the difference:

```
def func(arr):
    d = {}
    return max(i - d.setdefault(x, i) for i, x in enumerate(arr))
```

**Update:** If the items on the list are not hashable or sortable then you need to compare them all against each other and that can be only done in **O(n^2)** time. You could improve the original code by starting the inner loop from `i+1` which would also get rid of `abs`. Another improvement would be to call `max` only once instead of after every match:

```
def func(arr):
    gen = (j - i for i in range(len(arr) - 1) for j in range(i + 1, len(arr))
           if arr[i] == arr[j])
    return max(gen, default=0)
```

Note that above only works on Python 3.x because `max` on 2.x doesn't support `default` parameter.

**Update:** The most efficient algorithm I could come up with to cover the scenario of unhashable/sortable items is to compare all pairs with difference of `len(arr) - 1` and if you don't find a match then compare pairs of `len(arr) - 2` and so forth. This is of course still **O(n^2)** in case that all items on the list are unique:

```
def func(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr) - 1, 0, -1):
        for j in range(len(arr) - i):
            if arr[j] == arr[j+i]:
                return i

    return 0
```

Comment: upvoted -- this is a good answer. The code's not functionally identical to the original though, because for example it assumes the items in the array are hashable.

Comment: I was going to ask if you need an `abs`, but you don't. Since it goes over the array in index order, the current index is always guaranteed to be greater than or equal to the one in the `dict`.

Comment: @PaulHankin: Thanks for highlighting the issue with hashing, totally forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a bit of a speed up by bringing that max() out to the top and using list comprehensions (although you'll still need to tackle the O notation complexity):

```
def func(arr):
    return max([abs(i - j)
                 for i in range(len(arr))
                   for j in range(len(arr))
                     if arr[i] == arr[j]])
```